# Stability of a Fixed Point Homework Help

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Determine the stability of all the fixed points of the following function: $f(x)=2\sin(x)$.

I've found the fixed points. They are $x=0$ and $x=1.895$. How can I determine the stability now?

Comment: Is this question fundamentally different from your previous question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936517/fixed-points-and-graphical-analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you evaluate $f$ at values of $x$ near your fixed points, does $f$ move toward or away from your fixed points? Look at the behavior of the derivative of $f$ to see what the slope is doing near those points.

Comment: So what would it say about the stability if it moves toward the fixed point from the left and also when it moves toward the fixed point from the right?

Comment: Great question! That is precisely when a fixed point is stable. $x=1.895$ should be a stable point. $x=0$ should not, because any small positive $x$ will move away as you iterate your function.

Comment: So if a fixed point is stable ,such as $x=1.895$, how can I determine if this stable point is repelling or attracting? Do I use the absolute value of its derivative?

Comment: All stable fixed points attract, because values of $x$ near those stable points move toward the stable points. If you have a fixed point that isn't stable, that is when repelling occurs, as values near unstable fixed points move away from the fixed point. 

I should add that things can get weird if you are working in higher than 2-dimension, or working with chaotic systems. But your function is well behaved.